# Dialog box height does not seems to appear correctly in excel 2016

Tags: office-js

I am showing the dialog box with height as 50% in excel 2016, but the dialog box appears to be bigger (as if it is 75%). See the attached picture from excel 2016. The size looks good in office 365, but appears bigger in office 2016. Is this a known issue? What should i do to fix it in office 2016? Please help.

```
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/Test.html", { height: 50, width: 23 });
```

[Please see this image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A4qd.png)

Comment: This is probably a bug. Is the height about 50% of the _screen_ height?

Comment: No, the dialog box height is not 50% of the screen height. It appears too big in excel excel 2016. So for now, I managed to adjust the content size based on the window size (i.e based on dialog box size).

Comment: What is the content of the test.html file?

Comment: I have a Telerik grid inside test.html file and I am adjusting the grid's height based on window height.